# Uniface - [error] 1638 - Fields can only be painted inside an entity frame

Tags: uniface

I want to create an EditBox (Multi-line) on the interface in Uniface 10 and I get the following error.

`[error] 1638 - Fields can only be painted inside an entity frame.`

How can I create an entity frame in uniface to solve this problem?